# Fetch Probability from Random Forest Classified Image

Tags: google-earth-engine, random-forest

[image]

I have performed random forest classification in Earth Engine would like to select only pixels with high probability. But I cant figure how it to be done. I see the probability value in the Inspector but cant figure out how to extract that value.

Answer (score 1):

That number is not a probability. (The Inspector doesn't know anything about classification.) It is the **mask** of the image, which being less than 1 (100%) indicates that the particular pixel you clicked on was only partially covered by the original image data (or that some other mask manipulation occurred). The classifier does not care about mask; the mask value is the same at the output of the classifier as at the input.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I don't fully understand this. This particular pixel was in the middle of a farm in which all pixels were classified as '1'. I have performed crop mask and a NDVI mask, but the pixels removed due to masking are no where near this pixel. So what is the 'Original Image' here?

Comment: @GeorgeBasil By "original image" I only mean "the input to the classifier". I can't say where it's coming from exactly — it would be necessary to experiment with the actual code to answer that. The one thing that I can tell you with certainty is that the % figure the Inspector displays is the mask value.

Comment: Thank you. Can the probability value be extracted from a classified image in any way? Finding a few pixels with high confidence from the classification image is what I'm aiming for so that I can visit there and conduct some fieldwork.

Comment: @GeorgeBasil Sorry, I'm not very familiar with classifiers. I believe some of them can be _run in a probability mode_, so that the band outputs would be probabilities instead of(?) a class, but I can't do better than "check the documentation" right now.